# Why is potassium phosphate KH2PO4 in this reaction?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, stoichiometry, ionic-compounds

This is a continuation of [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64205/help-balancing-reaction-between-iron-ii-chloride-and-potassium-phosphate) because the first thing that came in my mind is that why potassium phosphate in this reaction is $\ce{KH2PO4}$ and not $\ce{K3PO4}$?

In the wikipedia article of [phosphate ion ($\ce{PO4^3-}$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphate), it is written that:

> Aqueous phosphate exists in four forms. In strongly basic conditions,
>   the phosphate ion ($\ce{PO4^3-}$) predominates, whereas in weakly
>   basic conditions, the hydrogen phosphate ion ($\ce{HPO4^2-}$) is
>   prevalent. **In weakly acidic conditions, the dihydrogen phosphate ion
>   ($\ce{H2PO4−}$) is most common**. In strongly acidic conditions,
>   trihydrogen phosphate ($\ce{H3PO4}$) is the main form.

**So, $\ce{FeCl2}$ must somehow be acidic in aqueous solution so as to protonate potassium phosphate $\ce{K3PO4}$ to $\ce{KH2PO4}$. Is this statement true?** [This question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58288/why-is-crcl3-acidic) throws some light on acidity of chromium chloride in aqueous solution but is it applicable to iron chloride as well?

---

In the previous question, the homework question was write the equation of reaction of Iron(II) chloride and **potassium phosphate**. So, students can assume the reaction to be $\ce{FeCl2 + K3PO4}$ to simply yield [iron(III) phosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_phosphate) or [iron(II) phosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II)_phosphate) and potassium chloride but why make the reaction complex by assuming potassium phosphate $\ce{KH2PO4}$.

Iron hydrogen phosphate are [new in this world and has been recently synthesised](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2009/dt/b902519g) and as not as stable as iron phosphates. So, can we just assume that reaction of Iron(II) chloride and potassium phosphate to yield iron (II or III) phosphate and potassium chloride?

Comment: Is there a reason students will assume that the Fe(II) ions are going to be oxidized to Fe(III) by phosphate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that’s just another mistake the OP of the other question made. Potassium phosphate is $\ce{K3PO4}$ and any student using any hydrogenphosphate instead would lose marks if I were marking the exam.

If $\ce{KH2PO4}$ is meant to be added, use the correct term: potassium dihydrogenphosphate.

This nomenclature can be found in the [current version of IUPAC’s Red Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/databases/Red_Book_2005.pdf), sections IR-8.2 and IR-8.4 and the anions in question are explicitly named in table IR-8.1 therein.

Comment: Potassium phosphate does not refer to K<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub> but refers to 3 different compounds whose actual IUPAC names are tripotassium phosphate, potassium hydrogen phosphate, and potassium dihydrogen phosphate. The rules for IUPAC naming were made to avoid this sort of confusion. The term "potassium phosphate" should never have been used.

Comment: Also never in my years of synthetic work have I ever come across tripotassium phosphate in a lab before.

Comment: @EframGoldberg No, that is not the case. Similar to sodium carbonate, which is $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and nothing else, potassium phosphate is $\ce{K3PO4}$ and nothing else. There is no need to add a *tri*-label as only one phosphate is possible (only one common oxidation state is known for potassium).

Comment: Irregardless of your opinion, the common name potassium phosphate has been used to describe all three compounds even requiring a wiki landing page for the term further specifying the three salts by IUPAC name. The three salts are commonly called potassium phosphate monobasic, dibasic or tribasic and are sometimes shortened in use. This and the fact that tripotassium phosphate is hardly encountered, are two important reasons to use IUPAC naming.

Comment: The analogy to sodium carbonate is not valid due to the common names being very different ie sodium carbonate and sodium bicarbonate, no one calls them sodium carbonate monobasic or dibasic. If both compounds could be referred to by the common name sodium carbonate, then IUPAC naming should be used as well, but that is not the case.

Comment: @EframGoldberg Please see the IUPAC Red Book; a link and the relevant sections are now provided in the answer. Potassium phosphate is $\ce{K3PO4}$ and nothing else. Case closed.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I can now point you to the exact section so you can see where you are wrong. Section IR2.13 Multiplicative Prefixes. "The number of identical chemical entities in a name is expressed by a multiplicative prefix." See example 5. Ca<sub>3</sub>(PO<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub> is tricalcium bisposhpate.

Comment: also the CA entry for CAS 7778-53-2 is phosphoric acid, tripotassium salt.

Comment: @EframGoldberg IR-5.2: ‘Multiplicative prefixes need not be used in binary names if there is no ambiguity about the
stoichiometry of the compound (such as in Example 10 above).’ Also, CAS uses a completely different nomenclature.

Comment: Looking at example 10, both tricalcium diphosphide or calcium phosphide are acceptable. The prefixes are considered superfluous unless describing compositionally related compounds which in this case holds true, as the term potassium phosphate has general usage for all three different compounds K3PO4, K2HPO4, and KH2PO4.

Comment: @EframGoldberg I urge you to take a look at the table I refer to in the post. You will see that *phosphate* clearly refers to the $\ce{PO4^3-}$ ion, *hydrogenphosphate* (the space I initially had in there was incorrect) to $\ce{HPO4^2-}$ and *dihydrogenphosphate* to $\ce{H2PO4-}$. In no way is it correct to refer to $\ce{KH2PO4}$ as *potassium phosphate,* since the entity ‘phosphate’ is not present. (The entity ‘dihydrogenphosphate’ is.)

Comment: I never said that was the correct name for KH2PO4, I said that (independent of the validity of doing so) the term potassium phosphate has been used to refer to all 3 compounds, and to avoid ambiguity the multiplicative prefix should be used. I also said this probably came from the fact that the compounds are sometimes called potassium phosphate mono, di, or tribasic... and likely people dropped the last part of it.

Comment: @EframGoldberg And my point throughout this entire discussion is that doing so is contradicting IUPAC’s nomenclature rules. I don’t care whether it is common; it is wrong. Wrong habits need to be combatted; at best it must be taught why they are wrong. Hence my answer in its current state.

Answer (score 2):

H<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub> is an acid usually present as 85% solution in water, while KH<sub>2</sub>PO<sub>4</sub> is a solid and therefore easier to handle, weigh etc. K<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub> is not a commonly used reagent in chemistry.

H<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub> is a polyprotic acid with pK<sub>a</sub> values as follows, 2.1, 7.2, 12.7. It will only be mostly PO<sub>4</sub><sup>-3</sup> at pH>12.7. Using the definition of pK<sub>a</sub>, a value of 7.2 for pK<sub>a2</sub> and assume pH = 7, and your calculations will explain why the ferrous chloride does not need to make the solution acidic to have H<sub>2</sub>PO<sub>4</sub><sup>-1</sup> exist as one of the major species.

I am still not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: If you’re not sure what is being asked, you should comment to ask for clarification.

Comment: @Jan I answered 3/4 questions that I could make out which were posted above, but the post is not asking a single question. There is a question about why a reactant was chosen, a question about speciation and pH, a question about Lewis acidity of metals, a question about oxidation reduction and general requests for clarifications. Perhaps the post can be edited to present only one clear question?

Comment: Just to reiterate: Yes, that should have been a comment on the question (ideally *before* answering).